# How to 'scale' a texture image to the object?

Tags: materials, uv

I am a newbie (first started using Blender last week) and have created some objects (which together make up the model I require) and need to apply a texture image to each object.

Following a video tutorial I have selected and applied a suitable texture image but the texture image appears too stretch along the Y axis. Looking at another video tutorial I went into 'UV editing', pressed Z and selected 'Material Preview', Selected the object (press A), and then attempted to apply scale by pressing S then X and also S then Y and dragged to what I considered correct. I checked the result on my image and the texture image is still stretched along the Y axis.

What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Lastly if I want to use an image with a vertical orientation to an object with a horizontal orientation can that be achieved inside Blender rather than me using an image editor to create a vertical image file?

[image: screenshot showing UV map and stretching]

[Added later]
Thanks to Marty's tutorial I now understand how to apply a texture/image to my object (easy once you have done it once) but having noticed that the placement of each face on the texture image affects the sharpness etc on the object. When I adjust the 'scale' on the X and Y axis to exceed the size of the object Blender then automatically adds more images to the object resulting in noticeable seams between each as the left side of the original image does not match the right side. Is there a way around this?

[image: example of seams]

Comment: The problem is either that your UV map is stretched, or that you're not using UV coordinates for your texture lookup.  It would take more information--preferably a file-- to be able to say which one that is, but based on the 3D pic you're showing, that doesn't look like an unstretched UV map.  You've already applied scale.  Now mark seams if necessary and unwrap the mesh.  See if you get the same UV map.

Comment: Have you actually unwrapped your object? - The image in the UV editor looks suspiciously like the default cube image which, presumably is what you used to create your object.

Comment: For your last question, yes you can rotate the texture by rotating the UV editor image by 90 degrees but that will rotate the texture on the entire object. As Nathan says, you need to add seams to your object to split it up and you can then select and rotate sections of the UV image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that you created a cube, stretched it along one axis, and then added a wood texture, something like this:  (I used a different wood texture but the idea is the same.)

[image: stretched cube]

[image: photo based texture material]

[image: UV Map on wood]

You can tell whether you applied the scale by looking at the sidebar in object mode:

[image: sidebar showing scale not applied]

in this example I scaled Y by 10 but didn't apply the scale.  In object mode, CTRL-A brings up the apply menu.

[image: apply menu]

Selecting scale fixes the scale:

[image: scale now applied]

But that doesn't fix the problem because you still have the default UV Map that was created when the cube was created.  So you need to create a new UV Map.  Here's the quick way to do that:

In edit mode, select all of the vertices of your rail.  Then use CTRL-E to bring up the edge menu.

[image: edit mode edge menu]

select "Mark seams".  Your beam will now have red edges to indicate that ever edge is a seam:

[image: all edges marked as seams.]

Next you have to unwrap the beam.  Because all the seams are in place you can use the shortcut U-key U-key (typing U twice.  That'll give you a UV map that looks like this one more or less:

[image: new UV map]

For me, this isn't enough, because the grain of the wood in the photo runs 90 degrees to the way wood would be cut for a beam.  To fix this I needed to rotate the UV map.  This is done by going into the UV edit window and then using the rotate and move tools to reposition the map.

The shortcut for this is 'a r 9 0 RETURN' to rotate and then 'g' to move.  left click to exit move -- this works just like in the 3d viewport

[image: after rotation]

[image: after move]

once that's done, my beam looks like this:

[image: final beam]

There is a lot more to UV unwrapping, like why I unwrapped each face separately, and other ways to manipulate the UV islands, but this answer is getting long.

Comment: Thanks all   I had applied scale of 1 to each axis already. YES I thought that I needed to do something with marking seems and although the video tutorial I watched mentioned it they did not explain how it was done (like so many tutorials which seem to assume too much and as such difficult for a complete newbie to not only Blender but also 3D modelling in general).

Comment: There's a quick tutorial on UVs and UV unwrapping [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM).